# Error when swapping panels in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I abstracted my problem into this simple application. When I try to navigate between panels, I find this error.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at application.TestPaneController.lambda$0(TestPaneController.java:22)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Main class

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("MainPane.fxml"));
            Pane painelTest = loader.load();

            Scene scene = new Scene(painelTest);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);
            primaryStage.show();
        } 
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Main application panel (Main.fxml)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane fx:id="mainPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <fx:include fx:id="testPane" source="TestPane.fxml"/>
    <fx:include fx:id="newPane" source="NewPane.fxml"/>
</Pane>
```

TestPane.fxml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane fx:id="testPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.TestPaneController">
    <Label fx:id="labelTitle" layoutX="26.0" layoutY="348.0" text="Test panel"/>
    <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="261.2275390625" layoutY="345.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="OK" />
</Pane>
```

TestPaneController class

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class TestPaneController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private Pane testPane;
    @FXML private Pane newPane;
    @FXML private Button button;
    @FXML private Label labelName;

    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        button.setOnAction(event->{
            testPane.setVisible(false);
            newPane.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

NewPane.fxml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane fx:id="newPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" visible="false" fx:controller="application.NewPaneController" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <Label fx:id="labelName" layoutX="200.0" layoutY="100.0" text="Hello"/>
    <Button fx:id="buttonBack" layoutX="261.2275390625" layoutY="345.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Back"/>
</Pane>
```

NewPaneController class

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class NewPaneController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private Button buttonBack;
    @FXML private Pane newPane;
    @FXML private Pane testPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        buttonBack.setOnAction(event->{
            newPane.setVisible(false);
            testPane.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

[printscreen: When I run the Main class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9X27.png)

[printscreen: After clicking the Ok button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fzne9.png)

The panel is null, I just do not know why

Comment: It is null because there is no pane with `fx:id="testPane"` in `TestPane.fxml`.

Comment: Look at TestPane.fxml again and you will see <Pane fx:id = "testPane">
The null panel I mentioned is 'newPane.fxml', the controller 'TestPaneController' is bringing '@FXML Pane newPane' with null value value

Comment: Yes, sorry, overlooked that. But the comment essentially holds: `TestPane.fxml` has no element with `fx:id = "newPane"`, so `newPane` is null.

Comment: But when I do '@FXML Pane private newPane;' Inside 'TestPaneController' should retrieve the panel, do you agree? The NewPane.fxml pane is inside MainPane.fxml (<fx: include fx: = newPane source = "NewPane.fxml" />), but is set to 'visible = false'. The responsibility of making this panel visible is of TestPanelController, when the 'Ok' button is pressed, but it can not do 'newPane.setVisible (true)', because newPane is equal to null

Comment: It can't magically retrieve it from the place you just happen to want it to retrieve it from. How on earth would that work? The `FXMLLoader` initializes `@FXML`-annotated fields in the controller when it loads the FXML file. There's no field with the corresponding `fx:id ` in the FXML file being loaded, so it doesn't get initialized.

Comment: Sorry for having responded to your comment before testing your solution in my code. It solved my problem in part. Thank you. When I click the 'Ok' button the error does not occur, and 'testPane' becomes invisible, as I programmed, but newPane does not appear, unlike what should happen. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no element of `TestPane.fxml` with `fx:id="newPane"`, so the `newPane` field in `TestPaneController` is null.

Since `newPane` is not part of `testPane`, it doesn't really make sense to give the responsibility of making `newPane` visible to the `TestPaneController`. You should do this in the controller for the main fxml file. The most robust and flexible approach to do this is to create an object which tracks which pane is currently visible. So I would do something like:

```
public class ViewState {

    private final ObjectProperty<Pane> currentView = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public ObjectProperty<Pane> currentViewProperty() {
        return currentView ;
    }

    public final Pane getCurrentView() {
        return currentViewProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setCurrentView(Pane view) {
        currentViewProperty().set(view);
    }
}
```

Now create a `MainController` class which references the loaded panes:

```
public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private Pane mainPane ;

    @FXML
    private Pane newPane ;
    @FXML
    private Pane testPane ;
    @FXML
    private NewPaneController newPaneController ; // field name is fx:id + "Controller"
    @FXML
    private TestPaneController testPaneController ;

    public void initialize() {
        ViewState viewState = new ViewState();
        viewState.currentViewProperty().addListener((obs, oldView, newView) -> {
            testPane.setVisible(newView == testPane);
            newPane.setVisible(newView == newPane);

            // or: for (Node n : mainPane.getChildren()) n.setVisible(n == newView);
        });

        // pass view state to "child" controllers:
        testPaneController.setViewState(viewState);
        newPaneController.setViewState(viewState);
    }

}
```

and of course reference this controller in the main fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane fx:id="mainPane" fx:controller="application.MainController" 
    prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" 
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

    <fx:include fx:id="testPane" source="TestPane.fxml"/>
    <fx:include fx:id="newPane" source="NewPane.fxml"/>
</Pane>
```

And finally modify the "child controllers" so they update the view state:

```
public class TestPaneController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private Pane testPane ;
    @FXML private Button button;
    @FXML private Label labelName;


    private ViewState viewState ;

    public void setViewState(ViewState viewState) {
        this.viewState = viewState ;
    }

    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        button.setOnAction(event->
            viewState.setCurrentView(testPane));
    }
}
```

Note that this design avoids the child controllers knowing anything about the parent pane or other children of the parent pane.

You could expand the functionality of `ViewState`, e.g. to keep a "history" and implement "Back" and "Forward" functionality, if you needed.